# Get Last Modified Azure Data Lake into table column SQL With SSIS

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-data-lake

I want to ask something about SSIS, that have an SSIS solution that has TASK Source Azure Data Lake, and Destination Azure SQL Database

In Azure SQL Database, I have added column DATEMODIFIED from Last Modified Azure Data Lake ...

The question is "can I get the last modified data CSV Azure Data Lake into Azure SQL DB table."?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, I think can use C# or Python script ... but I do not have any references for this issue

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `script task` in your package and use the **System.IO.FileInfo** object in the script task to get the file properties including the file's last modified date.

You could also use REST API call or SDK as suggested in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184374/i-need-to-get-file-last-modified-dates-of-data-lake-files-in-ssis) thread.